# How can I get Google drive API to authenticate?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I am struggling a lot to get my authentication to work for Google drive api.

This is my current code.

```
const drive = google.drive({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            keyFile: 'google-cloud-credentials.json',
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
        }),
    });
```

No matter what I try, I get the error `"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/google-cloud-credentials.json'"`

I've also tried the following:

```
keyFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'google-cloud-credentials.json'),

keyFile: './google-cloud-credentials.json',

keyFile: '../google-cloud-credentials.json',

keyFile: '../../google-cloud-credentials.json',
```

I should mention that I'm also deploying with with *Serverless* but in the past I've been able to get this to work.

Comment: Your error message only means that the credentials.json file is not in your directory. Please double check if it is there.

Comment: It is definately in my directory. I managed to figure a way around it but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

So I found in the type definition for GoogleAuth that you can simply use `credentials` which takes the body of the credentials rather than `keyFile` which takes the path.

After that I just simply had to import JSON into my file and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how you Auth. that's just creating google Auth object. you must fill it with credentials or it will do nothing.

maybe read the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) again. there's a standard implementation of oauth there. also feel free to ask a follow up

Comment: I have the credentials from a service account I created, in the root my of project. My only issue was that GoogleAuth was unable to find it no matter how I defined the file path. I solved it by directly importing JSON into the file under credentials in GoogleAuth. Sorry if my original question wasn't clear.